# Laravel 5.4 Route [project.view] not defined

Tags: php, laravel-5, controller, routes

Alrighty, so I have a page in which I load my projects for visitors to watch:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Projects')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="contact-wrapper ">
            <h1 class="text-center">Project overview</h1>
            @foreach($projects as $project)
                <div class="col-md-4 no-padding">
                    <div class="project-image col-md-12 no-padding">
                        <a href="{{ route('project.view', $project->id) }}">
                            <img src="{{ $project->image }}" class="col-md-12 image">
                            <p class="image-text">
                                {{ $project->title }}
                            </p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
@stop
```

But I'll get the following error:

```
Route [project.view] not defined. (View: /home/vagrant/Code/test/resources/views/projects.blade.php)
```

While I defined it in my web.php route file as shown below

```
<?php


Auth::routes();


Route::get('/', 'HomeController@welcome');


Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']],  function() {
    Route::resource('user', 'UserController', ['only' => ['index', 'show']]);
    Route::resource('project', 'ProjectController', ['only' => ['index', 'show', 'view']]);
    Route::resource('blog', 'BlogController', ['only' => ['index', 'show']]);
    Route::resource('review', 'ReviewController', ['only' => ['index', 'show']]);
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::resource('user', 'UserController', ['only' => ['store', 'update', 'destroy', 'create', 'edit', 'search', 'cms']]);
    Route::resource('project', 'ProjectController', ['only' => ['store', 'update', 'destroy', 'create', 'edit', 'search', 'cms']]);
    Route::resource('blog', 'BlogController', ['only' => ['store', 'update', 'destroy', 'create', 'edit', 'search', 'cms']]);
    Route::resource('review', 'ReviewController', ['only' => ['store', 'update', 'destroy','create', 'edit', 'search', 'cms']]);
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

and in my ProjectController.php I defined the function as shown below

```
 public function view($id)
    {

        $projects = Project::findOrFail($id);

        $users = User::all();

        $userArray = [];
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $userArray[$user->id] = $user->username;
        }


        return view('project.view', compact('projects', 'userArray'));
    }
```

I've read about how resource controller only can handle the standard Index/Show/Update etc etc function but how can I route this correctly so it'll just my function from the ProjectController?

I have the views in the correct folder and I am 99% sure I have called them correctly. The path to the view is: resources/views/project/view.blade.php

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are right resource controller default routes are what laravel have defined it. I mean `show`, `store` etc. when you have to add further method in resource controller in your case `view` you have to write a new route with `Route::get('project-view','ProjectController@view')` something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already mentioned resource controllers only handle the default CRUD actions. As i know you can't override this behaviour (which isn't intended anyway)

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers

If you want to name your route different you can "rename" it, but if you want to add other Routes/Actions to your controller you'll have to define seperate Routes for it (like Route::get, Route::post etc.)